# Is it possible for JavaScript to prevent people from right clicking to save images?

Tags: javascript, privacy

I have been studying JavaScript and I've found so many things what it can do and I feel comfortable using this language, but I'm getting worried about the right click savers out there. Is there a way to prevent people from ever saving the images from my website and put it onto their desktop?

1. Some girl
2. Some person
3. That person took the images
4. Store it on his/her desktop
5. Makes fun of the girl

Comment: Even if you could do this effectively (which you can't), what about print screen? What about someone physically taking a photo of the screen?

Comment: And on another note, the girl should simply not put images online if she is uncomfortable with them being visible to anyone, forever.

Comment: If you are showing them an image, then they can save the image. The only thing you can do is make it more annoying to save that image.

Comment: First why break the browsers default functionality.  Second why post it on the web if you don't want people viewing, saving, sharing, thats what makes the web great!.

Answer (score 7):

No, there isn't any way to do this that isn't easily circumvented.

Answer (score 2):

You can put some overlay onto  the image, but that wont stop people with a dev console for their browser.

Another way is to load images from a script and only allow them to be shown when they are on a certain page (using php or any other server implementation)

Answer (score 1):

No. If someone has gone to your web page and can see your image the browser has already downloaded the image and saved it to the local cache, whether or not the user knows how to get to it.

Also, they can always turn off Javascript in their browser

Answer (score 1):

You can make it hard to download the image but it's IMPOSSIBLE to prevent image theft!

Using a grid of small images and showing just a part of whole image when user zoom in is the way most photography site uses to make it hard to steal the image. When you use grid of images then drag and drop or Save As wouldn't save whole image.

But it's still possible to steal the image by collection all parts of image and connecting them together via an image editing tool